# how to use net::https in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
Net::HTTP.get_print URI.parse('http://www.example.com/index.html')
```

when i tried to run this programm  i getting error like this why??

```
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: no address associated with hostname. (SocketError)
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:48:in `timeout'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:379:in `get_response'
    from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:337:in `get_print'
    from ruby2.rb:3
```

Comment: works fine here. are you maybe missing a step of going through a proxy or something?

Answer (score 0):

the code looks correct and runs as expected on my machine - are you sure that dns is set up correctly on your machine? do you need a proxy to make web-calls? can you open the url in a browser?

Comment: no but i can open a particular url in brower for that url im tring this code but its not working

Comment: the html-sourcecode of the referenced site gets printed on the console.

Comment: Nikolaus i do n't have access to net but one particular url is there that i can open i put that url in my code it's not working
tell me soultion wht should i do now

Comment: try to access the server by ipadress instead of the hostname to test if your code breaks at the nameserver resolution - if this works make sure the nameservers are configured corretly on your machine or enter the ip/hostname pair into the hosts file

Comment: sorry but i didn't get you ip/hostname pair into the hosts file
what does that mean

Comment: this is how your computer translates hostnames to ip adresses

Comment: c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize': Bad file descriptor - connect(2) (Errno::EBADF)
i tried with ipaddress but i got this above plus all error before

Comment: how do i enter this ip/hostname pair into the hosts file means and file file means where i put this code??

Comment: you don't do that in your code, its how your computer is configurated

Comment: now i what should i do i really need to rub this code what to do

Comment: anything else i can do???
i also tried with ip adress but its giving error bad file descriptor

Comment: sorry i'm out of ideas - maybe try it on another computer

Answer (score 0):

I don't, I get a response. Were you online at the time?

Comment: Amadan i m using particular url that i can open for that i am tring this code but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try triangulating the problem. You can reach sites from your browser, but not from your code:

1. From a command-line window run: `gem server` to get a nice little web server running.
2. Open a browser window to the gem server, using: `http://localhost:8808`. You should see a nicely formatted page.
3. Run your code, adjusting the URL to point to the gem server at the address above. You should see output, probably a lot of it.
4. If you get output, you can kill the gem server using `<CNTRL>+C`. At that point you've proven Net::HTTP is working locally and you're done except for figuring out what is external to your machine that is keeping you from seeing "example.com".
5. If you get no output, add `require 'open-uri'` to your list of requires in your code, and replace the HTTP::Net line with `puts open('http://localhost:8808').read` and try running the code again.
6. If you get no HTML scrolling by something in your Ruby networking stack is wrong.

At that point you'll know enough to add more detail to your original question by editing it.

Another thought comes to mind: You're on Windows. Do you have any networking security enabled, like a firewall? Could it be that it's blocking Ruby from creating a connection but allowing your browser?